# Error handling in Express after axios call

Tags: node.js, express, axios

I'm working on building a proxy app using express + axios (for the first time). Basically all the app will do is retrieve some data from an API and then send the response using express.

```
async function getInfo() {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(url);
    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    return error.response.data;
  }
}

const info = getInfo();

export default (req, res) => {
  return res.status(200).send(info);
};
```

I'm a bit confused on how to handle errors if the API returns an error, as part of the default export for Express should I have a condition for each error code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code :

```
const response = await axios.get(url);
```

Here [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) will provide you the complete API response, there you can get the status code and error details or success etc. But if you do not want to handle it there you can also manage it where you are calling the function.

How to handle error in Axios you can check [here](https://github.com/axios/axios#handling-errors)

In case if you print the info variable it is returning a promise. Just use the `.then()` as follows:

```
getInfo().then((result) => {
   //here the result will give you the error, success, status code etc.
})
```

In your code, you can try the following code to send the response to express.

```
 export default async (req, res) => {
   async function getInfo() {
    try {
      await axios.get(url).then(function (response) {

            return response;
        }).catch(function (error) {

            return error;
        })
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.response) {
        return error.response
      } else if(error.request) {
        return error.request
      }
    }
   }

  return await getInfo().then((result) => {
    if(result.error) {
         res.status(result.error.status).send(result);
    } else {
         res.status(200).send(info);
    }
  })
};
```

Comment: Thanks, how would I then send this response in Express?

Comment: let me know if you are getting any issue

Answer (score 0):

return the error as is from axios, it should contain all the relevant information including status code and details about the error (unless you want to attach further information to it)